# How can I show the custom error page on remote access?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

**Context:**

We want to use a custom error page to show errors to the user.

In the `Global.asax` file uses the `Application_Error` hook to forward all errors to the custom error page in our `ErrorController`. This is `~/Error/Index`. The `Global.asax` has the following code:

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    var lRedirectController = "Error";
    var lRedirectAction = "Index";

    [...]

    var lStatusCode = ?; // will be set dependent on the exception. E.g. 403

    HttpContextWrapper lContextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
    RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", lRedirectController);
    routeData.Values.Add("action", lRedirectAction);
    routeData.Values.Add("pStatusCode", lStatusCode);
    routeData.Values.Add("pIsAjaxRequest", lContextWrapper.Request.IsAjaxRequest());

    [...]

    // execute error controller
    using (ErrorController lController = new ErrorController())
    {
        RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(lContextWrapper, routeData);
        lController.BaseExecute(requestContext);
    }

    Response.End();
}
```

The `ErrorController` has the following code in the `Index` action:

```
public ActionResult Index(bool pIsAjaxRequest = false, string pMessage = null, int pStatusCode = 500, Exception pException = null, string pAdditionalInfo = null)
{
    // assign the status code to the response header
    Response.StatusCode = pStatusCode;

    // [...]

    // if it was an ajax request, return json, else the view
    if (!pIsAjaxRequest)
    {
        // [...]

        return View("Index", "_BlankPage");
    }
    else
    {
        // json response
    }
}
```

The file `web.config` in the root folder has **no** declaration for `<customErrors mode="On"/>`. If I add it or not, the behaviour is the same.

**Problem:**

When I execute an error on my local machine, the custom error page will be shown as expected. But when I call the application from another machine via the browser over network, then I get any other error page:

[image]

**Question:**

How can I show the custom error page on remote access?

Comment: please read on [here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Comment: @crai: I think you have not correcly red my question: 'If I add it or not, the behaviour is the same.' In addition, the page behind your link is talking about the YSOD. As you can see the screenshot in my question, it is not a YSOD.

Comment: ok, got it, please see the in answers

Answer (score 0):

Your error page

Error.cshtml

put values from ErrorModel

```
 public class ErrorModel
    {

       public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
       public bool IsHttpException { get; set; }
       public string ViewFile { get; set; }
       public string ErrorUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error()
        {

            Exception currentEx = Server.GetLastError();
            ErrorModel errorDetail = null; 
            try
            { 
                errorDetail = ConstructError(Context, currentEx);                 
                Context.Items["ErrorObject"] = errorDetail;                 
                Server.ClearError();
                Context.Response.Clear();  
                ReportError();

            }
            finally
            {
                Cleanup(Context, errorDetail);
            }
        }

        private static void Cleanup(System.Web.HttpContext context, ErrorModel errorInfo)
        {

            if (errorInfo != null && !errorInfo.IsAjax && errorInfo.ErrorCode == 500)
            {
                if (context.Session != null)
                {
                    context.Session.Abandon();
                }
            }
        }

        private static ErrorModel ConstructError(System.Web.HttpContext context, Exception currentEx)
        {
            var model = new ErrorModel();            

            model.IsHttpException = currentEx is HttpException;
            model.ErrorCode = model.IsHttpException ? ((HttpException)currentEx).GetHttpCode() : 500;

            model.ViewFile = "~/Views/Error.cshtml";
            model.ErrorUrl = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

            return model;
        }

        private void ReportError()
        {
            Context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            var httpWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);

            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "index");

            var requestCtx = new RequestContext(httpWrapper, routeData);            

                var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(requestCtx, "Error");
                controller.Execute(requestCtx);


        }
```

In ErrorController

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Retrieve error object from either HttpContext or Session
    ErrorModel err = this.HttpContext.Items["ErrorObject"] as ErrorModel ?? Session["ErrorObject"] as ErrorModel;           

    this.Response.ClearHeaders();             
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        Response.Write(RenderToString(err.ViewFile, err));

}

  private string RenderToString(string controlName, object viewData)
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, controlName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, new ViewDataDictionary(viewData), TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```